# ASP NET tengo un problema para compartir entre modelo y vista

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc

En mi proyecto tengo un login y quiero que el nombre del usuario se pueda utilizar en el cshtml.

Lo tengo en modo MVC y estos son mis ficheros:

**LoginModel.cs**

```
namespace MVC_Catálogo_Imágenes.Models
{
 public class LoginModel
 {
  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obligatorio")]
  public string? User { get; set; }

  [Required(ErrorMessage = "Campo obligatorio")]
  public string? Password { get; set; }
 }
}
```

**Controller.cs**

```
public ActionResult Login()
{            
   return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel l)
{
 try
 {
  using (SqlConnection con = new(_contexto.Valor))
  {
   using (SqlCommand cmd = new("sp_login", con))
   {
    cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Usuario", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = l.User;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Pass", System.Data.SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = l.Password;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Estado", System.Data.SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
    con.Open();
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    int count = result == null ? 0 : Convert.ToInt32(result);
    con.Close();
    if (count > 0)
    {
    IsAuthenticated = true;
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
    ViewData["error"] = "Usuario y/o contraseña incorrectos";
    return View();
    }
   }
  }
 }
 catch (Exception)
 {
  ViewData["error2"] = "Ha habido un error al iniciar sesión";
  return View();
 }
}
```

**Profile.cshtml**

```
@model LoginModel
<h5>@Model.User</h5>
```

Pues al llamar al modelo desde la vista, me da este error:

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor.RazorPage.Model.get devolvió null.

Comment: Tu vista (`Profile.cshtml`) es una vista fuertemente tipada (strongly typed view) y espera un modelo `@model LoginModel`. Tu controlador debería pasar ese modelo a la vista a través de `return View(model);`

Comment: Hola @Arriel gracias por su respuesta.

He probado también ese método:
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", l);

pasando l como parámetro, pero este sólo sirve en esa vista a la que se redirige, si cambio a otra vista, el valor del usuario en el modelo vale null de nuevo

Comment: Bueno. Asegúrate de pasar el modelo en el momento que retornas la vista para evitar ese error.

Comment: Percibo que estás iniciando con ASPnet MVC, te sugiero revisar este workshop: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6LZG76aLykY&list=PL-_pdwtmHN2TcXVCoDc0qSqzwRFgJarO_&index=14 esas 4 horas son un resumen de un curso de 27 horas que llevé en lo que fue la Microsoft Virtual Academy, espero te sea de utilidad. Saludos.